# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' while execute pelican-quickstart

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, pelican

I'm trying to build a static site using Pelican with Git Pages but I got this little problem when execute the command `pelican-quickstart` .

I got this on the prompt:
[image: image of output]

Any ideas? I found [this](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/issues/2043) on pelican's github but I don't really understand what exactly I must do to fix this issue.

I'm using Python 3.5, Pelican 3.7.0 inside a virtualenv.

Comment: You can post a minimal working example

Comment: The error points to `locale.getlocale() [0]` being `None`

Comment: But the most simple command from Pelican doesn't work, it's my point. I couldn't think on anything useful to use as example. Sorry :(

Comment: [Known issue](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/issues/2043) with a [fix](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/pull/2068) on the way.

Answer (score 3):

For same unknown reason, my file `pelican-quickstart.py` doesn't verify the lenght of `sys.version_info.major` . So I just put these two lines on the code:

`if (sys.version_info.major >= 2): locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')`

Just below the line `from pelican import __version__` .

This works pretty well for me. The solution comes from [this code snippet](https://github.com/lucasplus/pelican/commit/fa905edd5f91f0938b88f95836c7df65e33c78b9#diff-52fe2de2a8486e716ec2398752ead4dd) .

Comment: If you're not sure where to find this file, by default pip installs it at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pelican/` (on Mac, Python version dependent).  Non-Mac can find the root path of the module by importing pelican and running 
`pelican.__file__`